# Gulp tasks - Run in sequence without dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, gulp

I have a global task that must run in sequence (synchronous) some sub-tasks. I used the task's dependencies mechanism to handle that "synchronous" logic :

```
// main task
gulp.task('deploy', ['build', 'upload', 'extract', 'migrate'], function() {
    // task returns a stream 
});

// sub tasks
gulp.task('migrate', ['extract'], function() {
    // task returns a stream
});

gulp.task('extract', ['upload'], function() {
    // task returns a stream
});

gulp.task('upload', ['build'], function() {
    // task returns a stream
});

gulp.task('build', [], function() {
    // task returns a stream
});
```

Dependencies works well and run all in sequence.
But now, how can I call `migrate` without executing `extract>upload>build`.
Because, sometimes I'll want to call manually :

```
gulp build
gulp upload
gulp extract
```

And I don't want each tasks to re-run all dependencies ...

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence seems to handle that logic, but I find it strange that gulp can't handle this common use case (or maybe I think 'grunt'  too much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the [run-sequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence) plugin does really well the job :

```
var runner = require('run-sequence');

// main task
gulp.task('deploy', [], function() {
    runner(
        'build',
        'upload',
        'extract',
        'migrate'
    );
});

// sub tasks
gulp.task('migrate', ['extract'], function() {
    // task returns a stream
});

gulp.task('extract', ['upload'], function() {
    // task returns a stream
});

gulp.task('upload', ['build'], function() {
    // task returns a stream
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean:build'], function() {
    // task returns a stream
});

gulp.task('clean:build', [], function() {
    // task returns a stream
});
```

This way I can independently call any sub-task without re-executing previous subtaks...

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is define (2) versions of each task I want to isolate, but have them call the same logic so I'm not repeating myself.

For example, in my current project, I have an `e2e-tests-development` task that depends on `build-development`, which builds both the server and the client before running e2e tests.  Sometimes I just want to re-run the tests and not re-build the entire application.

My `e2e-tests-development.js` file looks roughly like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
// Omitted...

gulp.task('e2e-tests-development',
    ['build-development'],
    _task);

gulp.task('e2e-tests-development-isolated',
    [], // no dependencies for the isolated version of the task.
    _task);

function _task() {
    // Omitted...
}
```

And obviously you'd invoke `gulp` with `e2e-tests-development-isolated` instead of `e2e-tests-development` if you want to just run that task.

(Of course what `gulp` really needs is a `--no-depedencies` flag from the command-line...)

Answer (score 0):

if you need the 2 version approach like I do, the following solution will do:

```
gulp.task('deploy:build', ['build'], function () {
    gulp.start('deploy');
}
```

Now I can call deploy without having a dependency on build.